# Import to excel from text file, with styling

Tags: excel, text

I have a program that saves text files, what I want to do is add some basic styling to this text, before they are opened in excel.

My files often looks like this:

```
Title of text

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Is there anything I could write in this text file that would make '*Title of text*' **bold** when opened in excel?

Like html tagging would be

```
<b>Title of text</b>

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Is there anything similar for excel?

Comment: You can add styling in excel yes, but are you trying to store the formatting in the saved text files, or in the excel file that opens the text?

Comment: @TimWilkinson I want to store the formatting in the text file, before I open it in excel, so the first time it opens in excel the Title will be bold

Comment: If you are saving your sheets as `.txt` or any other raw text format you won't be able to achieve this. You would have to export as HTML or a word doc for example to retain any styling you add.

Comment: @TimWilkinson I suspected as much, if you make an answer I will accept it (in a day or two, have to keep up hope). Since if this is the truth, this is the only answer I can accept

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code. This code will format text in range `A1:A13`. You can select range which you want to format according your needs. Just copy this code to Visual Basic editor and that run the sub using Run Sub button.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim str As String
Dim nBold As Long
Dim nEndBold As Long
Dim nChars As Long
Set Rng = Range("A1:A13")

For Each cell In Rng
    str = cell.Text
    nBold = InStr(str, "<b>")
    If nBold > 0 Then
        nEndBold = InStr(str, "</b>")
    If nEndBold = 0 Then nEndBold = 32767
        nChars = nEndBold - nBold - 3
        str = Replace(Replace(str, "<b>", ""), "</b>", "")
        cell.Value = str
        cell.Characters(nBold, nChars).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Look at [this link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/converting-b-to-bold-in-excel.986272/) for more information.